# Unix Script is taking longer time, can we optimise it

Tags: unix

```
seq_no=1
for line in `cat temp1_other.txt`
do
    pk=`echo "$line" | cut -d '|' -f41`
    seq_no=`expr "$seq_no" + 1`
    line1=`sed -n ''$seq_no'p' temp1_other.txt`
    pk_next=`echo "$line1" | cut -d '|' -f41`
        if [ "$pk" == "$pk_next" ]; then
        echo $line >> exam_duplicate.txt
        else
        echo $line >> exam_non_duplicate.txt
        fi
done
```

Trying to read a file and comparing current line column and next line column to check for duplicate record, for 60k-70k file it's taking more than 20 mins, can we optimise it or achieve it with some other logic. while loop also taking longer time. The records are sorted using "sort" command.

Sample Data:

```
Sam|1|IT|1st_Sem
Sam|1|CS|1st_Sem
Sam|1|CS|2nd_Sem
Peter|2|IT|2nd_sem
Ron|2|ECE|3rd_sem
```

Suppose 2nd column is the key column, if the 2nd column is matching with the next line 2nd column, it should go to duplicate file, if not matching then it should go to non duplicate file.

```
Sam|1|IT|1st_Sem
Sam|1|CS|1st_Sem
Peter|2|IT|2nd_sem
```

Should goto duplicate file and rest to non duplicate.

Comment: Please, post some sample data and the expected output.

Comment: If you are trying to read the file one line at a time `for line in $(cat temp1_other.txt)` will break horribly if the line contains any whitespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running Linux/bash ? Than you can try

```
tac temp1_other.txt | sort -k2,2 -t'|' -u > exam_non_duplicate.txt
```

The sort only looks to the second field and wants to keep the first record it sees.
You want to have the last record as non-duplicate, so we reverse the `cat` into `tac`.

Now you want to have the file with all duplicates, you can try

```
grep -vFxf exam_non_duplicate.txt temp1_other.txt > exam_duplicate.txt
```

This solution will fail when you have real duplicates (complete identical lines) when one of these is mentioned in the `exam_non_duplicate.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

Spawning external `cut` is going to kill your performance.  Do the whole thing in awk:

```
    awk '{this=$2} 
    NR>1 {
        output = "exam" (this != prev ? "_non" : "") "_duplicate.txt";
        print last > output
    }
    {prev=this; last = $0} ' FS=\| input-file
```

(This uses your example keying on column 2.  Change `$2` as necessary.)  Note that this will not write the final line of the file anywhere, but that's easy enough to handle.

Comment: How to parametrize the file name like:

        file=$1
        output = "$file_exam" (this != prev ? "_non" : "") "_duplicate.txt";

Comment: @pradeeppanda There are many ways to parameterize.  If you put this in a script, you might use `awk '... output = basename "exam" ...' FS=\| basename=$file`, where `file` is a shell variable holding the name.